# Create and send auto-generated emails in Node.js with Gsuite

Tags: javascript, node.js, email

I am currently trying to figure out how to send auto-generated emails from a Node back-end using GSuite.  I will be using a single email address (i.e. support@mywebsite.com) to send emails such as password resets or notifications.  I can't find any answers that actually work.

I have found nodemailer, and that is what I was intending to use, however, I read that Google is ending support for "less secure apps" which makes it so that I can no longer use this method, I think.  I would really appreciate some guidance on this.

I have tried nodemailer, but it just always says "Username and password not accepted."  I have checked and rechecked it many times, they are both correct.  I have tried adjusting "SMTP relay service" according to this: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en, but it changes nothing.

Here is my code for nodemailer:

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp-relay.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    auth: {
      user: "support@mycompany.com",
      pass: "myPassword"
    }
  });

const mailOptions = {
    from: "support@mycompany.com",
    to: "someperson@gmail.com",
    subject: "test",
    html: `<h1>Test</h1><p>Test</p>`
}


transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        return res.redirect("/");
    }
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the Google side of it: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en ?

Comment: Isn't that resource for "Less secure apps"?  The exact thing that they are removing in a few months?  I really have no idea, this is all completely new to me and I don't really understand it.  I will add to my question with what I tried and some code.

Comment: Use firestore they have services that make this very easy. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore